# Is matrix inversion stable?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

As the title suggests, if I perturb the entries of an arbitrary matrix by a very small value (say increase every entry by 0.01), how different will the inversion of this perturbed matrix compared to the inversion of the unperturbed matrix? What is the proper tool to do such analysis? Finally, is positive semi-definite matrix special in this respect (this is the case I am interested in)?

Sorry for being not clear enough before, the matrix I'm interested in actually has the following form (heat map):

[image]

It is a RBF ([radial basis function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function)) kernel matrix with the largest value along the diagonal entries and the values becomes smaller as they get further from the diagonal.

Comment: In general, the closer the determinant is to zero the more unstable this is. Consider the formula for the inverse in terms of the adjugate divided by the determinant.

Comment: Think about $1\times 1$ matrices.

Comment: The answers show that the type of matrix is not important. Why did you add that to the question?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the inversion operator is a homeomorphism on the space of invertible matrices, so it is continuous of course. Moreover, it is differentiable.  To quantify how far the inversion matrix is perturbed, given a slight perturbation on the origin matrix, we assume $M$ and $\delta M$ are invertible matrices, and ask for the optimal (or at least acceptable) constant $C$ such that

$$
\| M^{-1} - (M+\delta M)^{-1}\| \le C\epsilon\tag{1}
$$

Here we assume $\|\delta M\|_F<\epsilon$, and we assume $\|\delta M\|_F < \frac 12 \|M^{-1}\|_F^{-1}$ for technical reasons.

Notice, from operator theory, that for any invertible matrix $H$ with $\|H\|<1$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is any norm you like,

$$
(I-H)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} H^n=I+H+H^2 +\cdots\tag{2}
$$

Since $\|H\|<1$, the RHS is convergent. This equality can be checked by computing $I-H$ with the RHS above. This formula results in the reformulation of the LHS of $(1)$ as

$$
\begin{align*}
(M+\delta M)^{-1} - M^{-1}&= -M^{-1}+M^{-1} (I + (\delta M) M^{-1})^{-1}\\
                          &= -M^{-1} + M^{-1} \sum_{n=0} ((\delta M) M^{-1})^n\\
                          &= M^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((\delta M) M^{-1})^n\\
                          &= M^{-1}(\delta M)M^{-1} (I - (\delta M) M^{-1})^{-1}
\end{align*}
$$

Hence we have

$$
\| M^{-1} - (M+\delta M)^{-1}\| \le 2 \cdot \|M^{-1}\|^2 \cdot \|\delta M\| <2 \cdot \|M^{-1}\|^2 \cdot \epsilon \tag{3}
$$

Here we let $C=2\cdot \|M^{-1}\|_F^2$, arrive at the concluson, that the matrix inversion of $M$ is stable, provided that the norm of its inversion is not too large (or equivalently, $\|M\|$ is not too small and the condition number $\kappa(M):= \|M\| \cdot \|M^{-1}\|$ is not too large). Notice the the Frobenius norm $\|\cdot \|_F$ that we use here can actually be replaced by any other consistent norms.

By the way, by attacking $(1)$, we have a by-product.

$$
\| (M+\delta M)^{-1} - M^{-1} - M^{-1}(\delta M)M^{-1}\| =  \|M^{-1}(\delta M)M^{-1}(\delta M)M^{-1} (I - (\delta M)M^{-1})\| = O(\epsilon^2)
$$

The above formula expresses the differentiation of the inversion operator. Let $\chi(M)=M^{-1}$ denote the inversion operator, then we have $d_\chi(H) = M^{-1} H M^{-1}$.

Comment: Just wondering if we set up a linear system Mx = I where I is the identity matrix, we can rephrase the problem into finding the condition number of a linear system (x=M^{-1}). Based on the result from the conditioning of linear systems, the condition number of Mx=b (here b is some vector) is exactly the condition number of M. But I couldn't see there is any restriction on the choice of ||M||. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just think of inverting a scalar number $a$, where machine precision $\epsilon$ is a fixed positive constant. If $a$ is near zero, the floating point approximation of $a^{-1}$ cannot be too accurate. I think there is a principle, goes like "don't divide a big number by a small number" or so.  This just explains it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're familiar with geometric series.

Take any submultiplicative [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm); that is a norm with $\lVert AB\rVert\leq\lVert A\rVert\lVert B\rVert$ for any two matrices $A$ and $B$. Given an arbitrary invertible matrix $A$, consider the perturbed matrix

$$X=A+U$$

where $\lVert U\rVert$ is small. Let $I$ be the identity matrix.

$$X=(I+UA^{-1})A$$
$$X^{-1}=A^{-1}(I+UA^{-1})^{-1}$$
$$=A^{-1}\Big(I-UA^{-1}+(UA^{-1})^2-(UA^{-1})^3+(UA^{-1})^4-\cdots\Big)$$

This is a result of the algebraic identity $I-B^{n+1}=(I-B)(I+B+B^2+\cdots+B^n)$. Taking $n\to\infty$, if $\lVert B\rVert<1$, then $\lVert B^{n+1}\rVert\leq\lVert B\rVert^{n+1}\to0$, so the left side converges to $I$, while the right side becomes an infinite sum (which converges absolutely). Therefore $(I-B)^{-1}=I+B+B^2+\cdots$ when $B$ is small enough.

We want $\lVert UA^{-1}\rVert\leq\lVert U\rVert\lVert A^{-1}\rVert$ to be less than $1$ so that the infinite sum is valid. So suppose $\lVert U\rVert<1/\lVert A^{-1}\rVert$; this quantifies how small the perturbation should be. Then the perturbation of the inverse is bounded as follows:

$$X^{-1}-A^{-1}=A^{-1}\Big(-UA^{-1}+(UA^{-1})^2-(UA^{-1})^3+(UA^{-1})^4-\cdots\Big)$$
$$\lVert X^{-1}-A^{-1}\rVert\leq\lVert A^{-1}\rVert\cdot\Big\lVert-UA^{-1}+(UA^{-1})^2-(UA^{-1})^3+(UA^{-1})^4-\cdots\Big\rVert$$
$$\leq\lVert A^{-1}\rVert\cdot\Big(\lVert UA^{-1}\rVert+\lVert(UA^{-1})^2\rVert+\lVert(UA^{-1})^3\rVert+\cdots\Big)$$
$$\leq\lVert A^{-1}\rVert\cdot\Big(\lVert UA^{-1}\rVert+\lVert UA^{-1}\rVert^2+\lVert UA^{-1}\rVert^3+\cdots\Big)$$
$$=\lVert A^{-1}\rVert\cdot\frac{\lVert UA^{-1}\rVert}{1-\lVert UA^{-1}\rVert}$$
$$\leq\lVert A^{-1}\rVert\cdot\Big(\lVert U\rVert\lVert A^{-1}\rVert+\lVert U\rVert^2\lVert A^{-1}\rVert^2+\lVert U\rVert^3\lVert A^{-1}\rVert^3+\cdots\Big)$$
$$=\lVert A^{-1}\rVert\cdot\frac{\lVert U\rVert\lVert A^{-1}\rVert}{1-\lVert U\rVert\lVert A^{-1}\rVert}$$

---

It seems you're using the max norm, $\lVert A\rVert_\infty=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|a_{i,j}|$. (To say "increase every entry by 0.01" is to say $\lVert U\rVert_\infty=0.01$ .)

This is not submultiplicative; instead, for $n\times n$ matrices, $\lVert AB\rVert_\infty\leq n\lVert A\rVert_\infty\lVert B\rVert_\infty$. But we can define a submultiplicative norm based on the max norm: $\lVert A\rVert_\star=n\lVert A\rVert_\infty$.

So, again consider $X=A+U$, where $\lVert U\rVert_\infty$ is small. From the first part of this post,

$$\lVert X^{-1}-A^{-1}\rVert_\star\leq\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\star\cdot\frac{\lVert U\rVert_\star\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\star}{1-\lVert U\rVert_\star\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\star}$$
$$n\lVert X^{-1}-A^{-1}\rVert_\infty\leq n\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\infty\cdot\frac{n^2\lVert U\rVert_\infty\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\infty}{1-n^2\lVert U\rVert_\infty\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\infty}$$
$$\lVert X^{-1}-A^{-1}\rVert_\infty\leq\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\infty\cdot\frac{n^2\lVert U\rVert_\infty\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\infty}{1-n^2\lVert U\rVert_\infty\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\infty}$$

provided that $\lVert U\rVert_\star<1/\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\star$, or equivalently $\lVert U\rVert_\infty<1/(n^2\lVert A^{-1}\rVert_\infty)$.