# Estimating the determinant of a large RBF( Radial basis function) kernel matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there any property of a potentially RBF ([radial basis function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function)) kernel matrix that can be leveraged on in estimating its determinant (at least in estimating if the determinant is large or small)? The caveat is the explicit values of each entries are not given and only some properties of it is known are as follows:

[image]

The image is the heat map of the matrix with the largest value along the diagonal entries and the values becomes smaller as they get further from the diagonal. Sorry for the wrong example given earlier on.

Comment: Your question is vague. The determinant is the product of eigenvalues so numerically it can be approximated.

Comment: @AlexR. in this case the question is rephrase into 'how to estimate the product of the eigenvalues of a PSD matrix'. In point is the matrix is not explicitly given but only some properties of it is given instead (for example: all the entries are small in magnitude). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The property that all entries are small in magnitude does not present an opportunity for analysis or computation. The matrix can always be scaled by a constant. A scaling changes the determinant, but we know exactly how.

Comment: Please do not assume that the abbreviation RBF will make sense to others. I assume that the matrix is still symmetric positive definite. If the entries decay rapidly as we move away from the diagonal, then it may be possible to use Gershgorin's circle theorem to estimate the eigenvalues and say something about the size of the determinant. We need information about the decay rate if we are to make progress on this front.

Comment: Let's say k(θ,θ′) =exp(−||θ−θ′||^2/(2*l^2)) the length scale l = 20

Comment: Sure, but there is more than one way to interpret this. Is this an absolute bound or a bound relative to one of two relevant diagonal entries or is it an asymptotic decay rate or something else?

Comment: If you are referring to how to interpret the expression, imagine the origin is at the top left corner, one axis is θ another is θ', and it is natural to have a matrix with the heat map above.

Comment: I am not. As I said, your expression can be interpreted in at least three different ways. They are:  an absolute bound $|a_{ij}| \leq k(i,j)$ or a relative bound $|a_{ij}|/\max\{|a_{ii}|,|a_{jj}|\} \leq k(i,j)$ or an asymptotic behavior $a_{ij}/k(i,j) \rightarrow c$ where $c$ is some suitable constant.

Comment: Your related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4362137/307944) suggests that you are interested in solving systems rather than computing the determinant? In general, there is little practical information hidden in the determinant and there is a whole range of associated condition numbers that are much more informative. If you have one of those rare cases where the determinant is actually needed for the application at hand, then please add a description to your question as such special cases are of significant interest to the community.

Comment: really my question is to investigate for what input the inverse of RBF kernel matrix is stable. The reason I have a separate post focused on determinant is because someone suggested the stability of the inverse largely depends on the size determinant while in my original post the main answer took the condition number route. In the case I am interested, both the length scale (decay rate) and inputs to the kernel can be adjusted, and I want to find a setting for which the inverse is stable.

Comment: As for the interpretation, really what I am trying to say is as the entry gets further from the diagonal, the pair of inputs to kernel becomes less similar and therefore the kernel value becomes smaller, as can be visualized from the heat map.